# Styling points generated by table to have varying opacity?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, style

I want the points generated by `Table` styled with increasing opacity.

For example, let's say I have `ListPlot[Table[n,{n,0,5}]]`. What I want here is to style the first point $(1,1)$ with 0.2 opacity, the second $(2,2)$ with 0.4 opacity, the thrid $(3,3)$ with 0.6 opacity and so on. How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be to work with raw `Graphics` primitives:

```
Graphics[
 {PointSize[0.05],
  Table[{Opacity[(n + 1)/5], Point[{n, n + 1}]}, {n, 0, 4}]
 },
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
]
```

[image: regenerated]

Answer (score 3):

```
data = Transpose[{Range[6], Range[0, 5]}];
ListPlot[{#} & /@ data, PlotStyle -> (Opacity[#/5] & /@ Range[1, 6]), 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
data = Table[n, {n, 0, 5}];
styleddata = Style[#, Red, Opacity[ (# + 1)/5], PointSize[.1]] & /@ data;

ListPlot[styleddata, PlotStyle -> None, PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]