# Inconsistent opacity of points in exported 3D graphics with vector image format

Tags: graphics3d, export, pdf-format, opacity

An input of 3D graphics of points with [specific opacities for each](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147604/styling-points-generated-by-table-to-have-varying-opacity) gives a correct output graphic in its worksheet, but its [exported graphic with vector format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87733/export-plot3d-in-mathematica-10-1-is-rasterized-by-default) (e.g. eps, pdf, etc) gives wrong opacities. The following is an example of this trouble:

```
g1 = Graphics3D[
  {
    {Black, Table[{Opacity[(n/100)^2], Point[{n, n, n}]}, {n, 0, 100}]},
    {Green, Table[{Opacity[(n/100)^2], Point[{n, n, 100 - n}]}, {n, 0, 100}]}
  },
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}
]
```

This gives the following as its output:

[image]

But its exported vector image via the code `Export["g1.pdf", Graphics[Inset[g1, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]]` gives the following:

[image]

How do I get a correct, consistent vector image?